# How to add time to DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to **add custom time to datetime in SQL Server 2008 R2**.

Following is what I've tried.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 03, DATEADD(mi, 30, DATEADD(ss, 00, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,GETDATE())))) as Customtime
```

Using the above query, I'm able to achieve it.

But is there any shorthand method already available to add custom time to datetime?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '03:30:00')
```

Comment: Hardly the right answer. @date + cast(@time as datetime), where date is of type datetime and time of type time

Comment: @MoonStom Your comment is wrong, because OP wants to add 'custom time', not just time. See there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3891

Answer (score 51):

For me, this code looks more explicit:

```
CAST(@SomeDate AS datetime) + CAST(@SomeTime AS datetime)
```

Comment: This is so much more readable and straightforward than all of the others - why complicate things?  Quick note: you cannot add or subtract `DATETIME2` fields in this manner.  [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server) does cover this issue.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(dd, 0,GETDATE()) + CONVERT(DATETIME,'03:30:00.000')
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any reason for using `CONVERT()`?

Comment: The query won't execute without using `CONVERT()`

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,HOW_MANY_MINUTES,TO_WHICH_TIME)
```

Here `MINUTE` is constant which indicates er are going to add/subtract minutes from `TO_WHICH_TIME` specifier. `HOW_MANY_MINUTES` is the interval by which we need to add minutes, if it is specified negative, time will be subtracted, else would be added to the `TO_WHICH_TIME` specifier and `TO_WHICH_TIME` is the original time to which you are adding `MINUTE`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Or try an alternate method using Time datatype:

```
DECLARE @MyTime TIME = '03:30:00', @MyDay DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

SELECT @MyDay+@MyTime
```

Comment: Error: `The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: Implicit conversion between TIME and DATETIME is possible but can be added one to another. Don't ask. Use DATETIME for both operators: `DECLARE @MyTime DATETIME = '03:30:00', @MyDay DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

SELECT @MyDay+@MyTime`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split the time, case it or any of that stuff. Convert the time to seconds since midnight, then add it to the date. This should work with any version of SQL that supports DATEADD and DATEDIFF.

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', '14:30:00'), '2021-01-01') AS 
COMBINED_DATETIME
```

Comment: You may need to CAST(given_day AS DATETIME) in last argument if it's DATE type. Other case mssql will say it cannot DATEADD seconds to DATE type. ("The datepart second is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.")

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
SELECT GETDATE()+'03:30:00'
```

Comment: That yields an incorrect answer. It adds three and a half hours to the current `GETDATE()`. The OP here wanted a static time component of `03:30:00` so it's necessary to either remove the current time (cast to DATE) or to set it to midnight (likely using `DATEDIFF` as in several other answers) before doing the math.

Comment: If you post such an answer, please include an explanation. Why do you think that your query solves the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me is the one in the comments from **[MoonStom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954407/moonstom)**, which I rewrite here for everyone to easily see:

`CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) + CAST(CAST('01:01:01.01' AS TIME) AS DATETIME) AS 'New Date'`

The idea is to convert the date to `DATETIME` type and the time part from `VARCHAR`, first to `TIME` and then to `DATETIME` type. You can also replace the `GETDATE()` with a variable containing the date in which you want to add the time and the `'01:01:01.01'` with a variable containing the time you want to add. **Note** that any more digits added to the time part might be ignored due to the precision supported by the `DATETIME` type in your SQL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The following is simple and works on SQL Server 2008 (SP3) and up:

```
PRINT @@VERSION
PRINT GETDATE()
PRINT GETDATE() + '01:00:00'
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,FLOOR(CONVERT(float,GETDATE()))) + '01:00:00'
```

With output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) 
Mar 15 2017  6:17PM
Mar 15 2017  7:17PM
Mar 15 2017  1:00AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DDate      date        -- To store the current date
DECLARE @DTime      time        -- To store the current time
DECLARE @DateTime   datetime    -- To store the result of the concatenation
;
SET @DDate      =   GETDATE()   -- Getting the current date
SET @DTime      =   GETDATE()   -- Getting the current time



SET @DateTime   =   CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(19), LTRIM(@DDate) + ' ' + LTRIM(@DTime) ));
;
/*
    1. LTRIM the date and time do an automatic conversion of both types to string.
    2. The inside CONVERT to varchar(19) is needed, because you cannot do a direct conversion to datetime
    3. Once the inside conversion is done, the second do the final conversion to datetime.
*/  

-- The following select shows the initial variables and the result of the concatenation
SELECT @DDate, @DTime, @DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dateportion DATE = GETDATE()  -- Date only field
DECLARE @timeportion TIME = '03:30:00' -- Time only field

select 
    @dateportion AS [Date],
    @timeportion AS [Time],
    CAST (@dateportion as DATETIME) + CAST(@timeportion as DATETIME) as [CustomTime];
```

| Date | Time | CustomTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-06 | 03:30:00.0000000 | 2023-11-06 03:30:00.000 |

Answer (score -4):

Start Day Time : `SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '00:00:00')`

End Day Time : `SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '23:59:59')`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.