# Trying to pull records in between two time ranges from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to display a count on a label for all the rows that fall between 6AM and 8AM. I have a `datetimepicker` that I want to also use to select the day for all the rows that should be counted. I have tried several different ways to format my `SELECT` statement but nothing has worked. I either get datetime conversion error or wrong syntax.

```
var sql = "SELECT RTFPressTableID" +
      "FROM RTFPressTables" +
      "WHERE PressCloseTime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, 'Date 06:00:00:000 AM',109) >= @Date AND CONVERT(DATE, 'Date 08:00:00:000 AM',109) <= @Date";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YourSQLismissingsomespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
var sql = @"SELECT RTFPressTableID
    FROM RTFPressTables
    WHERE PressCloseTime BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date), '06:00:00') AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @Date), '08:00:00')";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; Integrated Security = True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date);
        command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Which has 3 changes from your code:

1. Spaces are added to the SQL string as mentioned in the comments. In fact using a multi-line string ([verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)) which is much easier to use for SQL strings.
2. The datatype of the `@Date` parameter is now of type `date` instead of `datetime`.
3. Most importantly the `between` statement is corrected to add the times to the date provided and use them as the limits.

Ref: [Add Time to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444884/how-to-add-time-to-datetime-in-sql/17444975)

Answer (score 3):

What date time should "`'Date 06:00:00:000 AM'`" represent?

And why do you use "`BETWEEN`" and then "`>=`" resp. "`<=`" in it's arguments? That's not the right syntax. Either use `BETWEEN` or `>=` and `<=`. Though I guess `<` is actually what you want for the second operator.

You probably want:

```
var sql = @"
SELECT RTFPressTableID
       FROM RTFPressTables
       WHERE PressCloseTime >= dateadd(hour, 6, @Date)
             AND PressCloseTime < dateadd(hour, 8, @Date);";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give spaces in your quotation marks after plus to avoid string concatenation. Something like this:

```
"SELECT RTFPressTableID" +
" FROM RTFPressTables" +
" WHERE PressCloseTime
```