# Sum of Timestamp and number of hours in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mysql-workbench

> Please help in achieving below result from mysql, I need to calculate
> sum

```
select CONVERT_TZ(current_timestamp,'UTC','US/Pacific'),SEC_TO_TIME(15080) as cal_hour_from_sec
```

> Current Output

```
CONVERT_TZ(current_timestamp,'UTC','US/Pacific'), cal_hour_from_sec

2020-07-15 02:53:26 04:11:20
```

> Desired Output(Sum of timestamp+hours)

```
2020-07-15  07:04:20
```

Comment: duplicated of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444884/how-to-add-time-to-datetime-in-sql) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add time to DateTime in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444884/how-to-add-time-to-datetime-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function TIMESTAMPADD:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND , 15080, CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'UTC','US/Pacific'))
```