# Concatenating date and time in SQL to get datetime: 1900-01-01 instead of actual dates error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table t1:(Have added Datetime1 column with no values initially, later want to update the values in `Datetime1` field. Type of `Date1` is date and type of `Time1` is time)

```
Date1         Time1         Datetime1
2021-07-19  02:00:00.000     NULL
2021-07-20  01:00:00.000     NULL
2021-07-21  12:00:00.000     NULL
```

I want to add another column `Datetime1` which will be the concatenation of both date and time

Expected output:

```
Date1         Time1         Datetime1
2021-07-19  02:00:00.000   2021-07-19 02:00:00.000
2021-07-20  01:00:00.000   2021-07-20 01:00:00.000
2021-07-21  12:00:00.000   2021-07-21 12:00:00.000
```

Code:

```
update t1
set Datetime1 = cast(concat(Date1,' ',Time1) as datetime)
```

I am getting wrong output after using this above code:

```
Date1         Time1         Datetime1
2021-07-19  02:00:00.000   1900-01-01  02:00:00.000
2021-07-20  01:00:00.000   1900-01-01  01:00:00.000
2021-07-21  12:00:00.000   1900-01-01  12:00:00.000
```

Instead of dates I am getting 1900-01-01, can anyone please tell what im doing wrong

Comment: I assume Date1 and Time1 are both strings?

Comment: No, Date1 is type date and Time1 is type time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add time to DateTime in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17444884/11683)

Comment: No it doesnt answer

Answer (score 4):

Convert both columns to `datetime` and then simply add them together

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date1] date,[Time1] time,DateTime1 datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2021-07-19','02:00:00.000',null)
,('2021-07-20','01:00:00.000',null)
,('2021-07-21','12:00:00.000',null)
 
Update @YourTable
   set DateTime1 = convert(datetime,[date1])+convert(datetime,[time1])
```

**Results**

```
Date1       Time1               DateTime1
2021-07-19  02:00:00.0000000    2021-07-19 02:00:00.000
2021-07-20  01:00:00.0000000    2021-07-20 01:00:00.000
2021-07-21  12:00:00.0000000    2021-07-21 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: @noob See updated answer